# Why my custom view call onDraw whenscreen turn on

Tags: android, screen, ondraw

I have a custom view,when i turn off the screen and turn on screen,the method onDraw will be called,i want to know why?

Comment: Because it has to be drawn most likely

Comment: How to abort?I want to keep the state when turn on the screen?Are there any configs to set?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to prevent the drawing from happening? Or rather, what exactly is the issue you're experiencing as a result of this re-draw happening?